Nested For runs really slow
Consider this simple code:
M = 400;
AbsoluteTiming[For[x = 1, x <= M, x++,
  For[y = 1, y <= M, y++,
   For[z = 1, z <= M, z++,
    i = 1]]]]

Above code runs really slow on my laptop which has Ryzen 7745HX CPU, more than 16 seconds to complete. The following equivalent Matlab code spends only 0.03 second on the same laptop.
M = 400;
tic
for x=1:M
  for y=1:M
    for z=1:M
      i = 1;
    end
  end
end
toc

Is this normal? Is there a way to address this issue? I am using WMA 14.

For loops are inefficient in WL and no experienced user uses them. There are better alternatives for them. Please read: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18396/43522

The For loop is not the whole problem here: even
AbsoluteTiming[Do[i = 1, M, M, M]]
(*    {4.50839, Null}    *)

takes very long. The problem is that the assignment to a global variable seems to be rather slow:
RepeatedTiming[i = 1]
(*    {6.74757*10^-8, 1}    *)

67 nanoseconds for setting a variable to an integer is, of course, rather long for a modern CPU. Better to do such things in a more appropriate programming language, not a high-level pattern engine like Mathematica.

Actually doing anything with Do[] is rather slow. Try AbsoluteTiming[Do[1==1, M, M, M]]. Faster is to do nothing as in AbsoluteTiming[Do[, M, M, M]] but still not a speed demon.

RepeatedTiming[Nothing] gives 5.3 ns, and Do[Nothing, 10^9] // AbsoluteTiming gives 7.2 s, so only 36% slower per call. The Do loop is slow compared to C, but not slow considering this is an interpreted language. For loops, on the other hand, are just terribly slow.
